# Reduce the list of products to only display the cheapest vendor

Tags: couchdb

I'm working with the http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/intro/tour.html example which works with the following setup:

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/demo
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/demo \
     -d '{"item": "apple","prices": {"Fresh Mart": 1.59,
                                     "Price Max": 5.99,
                                     "Apples Express": 0.79}}'
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/demo \
     -d '{"item": "orange","prices": {"Fresh Mart": 1.99,
                                      "Price Max": 3.19,
                                      "Citrus Circus": 1.09}}'
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/demo \
     -d '{"item": "banana","prices": {"Fresh Mart": 1.99,
                                      "Price Max": 0.79,
                                      "Banana Montana": 4.22}}'
```

It uses the following map to display all items:

```
function(doc) {
  var shop, price, key;
  if (doc.item && doc.prices) {
      for (shop in doc.prices) {
          price = doc.prices[shop];
          key = [doc.item, price];
          emit(key, shop);
      }
  }
}
```

But it displays all items multiple times:

[image: Screenshot of the results]

How can I write a reduce function which only displays the cheapest vendor of each item? How can I find the answer to the "Where can I buy the cheapest apple?" question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduce function is not the right tool for this. The answer to the question is an other map function. The following map function does the job:

```js
function(doc) {
  var shop, price, key;
  if (doc.item && doc.prices) {
    var cheapest = 99999999999;
    var cheapestshop = null;
    for (shop in doc.prices) {
      price = doc.prices[shop];
      if (price < cheapest) {
        cheapest = price;
        cheapestshop = shop;
      }
    }
    emit([doc.item, cheapest], cheapestshop);
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Futon]